# check type within numpy array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, isinstance

I have different types of data. most of them are `int` and sometimes `float`. The `int` is different in size so 8/ 16/ 32 bits are the sizes.
For this situation I'm creating a numerical type converter. therefore i check the type by using `isinstence()`. This because I have read that `isinstance()` is less worse than `type()`.

The point is that a lot of data i get is numpy arrays. I use spyder as IDE and then i see by the variables also a type. but when i type `isinstance(var,'type i read')` i get `False`.

I did some checks:

```
a = 2.17 
b = 3 
c = np.array(np.random.rand(2, 8))
d = np.array([1])
```

for there `isinstance(var,type)` i get:

```
isinstance(a, float)
True
isinstance(b, int)
True
isinstance(c, float)  # or isinstance(c, np.float64)
False
isinstance(d, int)  # or isinstance(c, np.int32)
False
```

`c` and `d` are True when i ask

```
isinstance(c, np.ndarray)
True
isinstance(d, np.ndarray)
True
```

i can check with step in the `ndarray` by

```
isinstance(c[i][j], np.float64)
True
isinstance(d[i], np.int32)
True
```

but this means that for every dimension i have to add a new index otherwise it is `False` again.
I can check there type with `dtype` like `c.dtype == 'float64'`...

Oke so for what i have find and tried...
My questions are basicly:

- how is the `var.dtype` method compared to `isinstance()` and `type()` (worst/ better etc)?
- if `var.dtype` is even worse as `isinstance()` is there some method in the `isinstance()` without all the manual indexing? (autoindexing etc)?

Comment: Where do you have this data with different integer sizes?  As Python objects, numpy arrays, files?  You may need to give more context for the use of the numerical type converter.

Comment: mostly multichannel audio files

Comment: And how do you intend to convert the data type?

Comment: from the int type/ numpy.intXX type change to (numpy.)float(64) and scale down with the integer size. So everything is -1 min to  +1 max

Comment: I added a note on `np.can_cast` and `.astype` to my answer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

An array is an object of type `np.ndarray`.  Its values or elements are stored in a data buffer, which can be thought of as a contiguous block of memory bytes.  The bytes in the data buffer do not have a type, because they are not Python objects.

The array has a `dtype` parameter, which is used to interpret those bytes.  If `dtype` is `int32` (there are various synonyms), 4 bytes are interpreted as an integer.  Accessing an element, say `c[0]` gives a new object that depends on the dtype, e.g. an object type `np.int32`.

`c[0].item` will give an Python object of the corresponding type:

```
In [2102]: c=np.array([1])
In [2103]: c.dtype
Out[2103]: dtype('int32')
In [2104]: type(c)
Out[2104]: numpy.ndarray
In [2105]: type(c[0])
Out[2105]: numpy.int32
In [2107]: c[0].item()
Out[2107]: 1
In [2108]: type(c[0].item())
Out[2108]: int
```

(And `c[0].dtype` is the same as for `c.dtype`; you don't need to index individual elements of an array to check their dtype).

The same 4 bytes of this array can be viewed as `dtype` `int8` - a single byte integer.

```
In [2112]: c.view('b')
Out[2112]: array([1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int8)
```

A single element of this alternate view is `np.int8`, but when I take `item()`, I get a Python integer.  There isn't a `int8` Python numeric type.

```
In [2113]: type(c.view('b')[0])
Out[2113]: numpy.int8
In [2115]: type(c.view('b')[0].item())
Out[2115]: int
```

A list contains pointers to Python objects, each of which has a type.  So does an array of `dtype=object`.  But the common numeric array does not contain Python integers or floats. It has a data buffer that can interpreted in various ways according to the `dtype`.  Python integers don't come in different sizes, at least not to the same extent as numpy dtypes.

So the `isinstance` and `type()` stuff does not apply to the contents of an `ndarray`.

====================

From the comments I gather you are trying to convert integer arrays to float.  You aren't converting scalars.  If so then `dtype` is all that matters; an array always has a `dtype`.  It's unclear whether you are ok with casting a `np.float32` to `np.float64`.

I'd suggest studying, and experimenting with the `np.can_cast` function and the `x.astype` method.

```
x.astype(np.float64, copy=False)
```

for example will convert all int dtypes to float, without copying the ones that are already float64.  It may copy and convert `np.float32` ones.

Look also at the `casting` parameter of these functions.

===========================

I found in `scipy.optimize.minimize` another testing tool

```
In [156]: np.typecodes
Out[156]: 
{'All': '?bhilqpBHILQPefdgFDGSUVOMm',
 'AllFloat': 'efdgFDG',
 'AllInteger': 'bBhHiIlLqQpP',
 'Character': 'c',
 'Complex': 'FDG',
 'Datetime': 'Mm',
 'Float': 'efdg',
 'Integer': 'bhilqp',
 'UnsignedInteger': 'BHILQP'}
```

It can be used to check for integers with:

```
if x0.dtype.kind in np.typecodes["AllInteger"]:
    x0 = np.asarray(x0, dtype=float)
```

Answer (score 9):

To directly answer the question, you can do this:

`isinstance(arr.flat[0], np.floating)`

- `.flat` will collapse any number of dimensions down, so you can then access the 0th element easily.
- `np.floating` will match any numpy float type

Comment: This assumes the array *has* a first element. It might not - arrays can have 0 elements. This is strictly inferior to a dtype check.

Answer (score 5):

A slight variation from @rasen58 and @hpaulj:

To check if an np array, `c`,  has elements of type float, `c.dtype == np.floating` works for me.

Comment: FWIW, when I tried this I got `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:79: DeprecationWarning: Converting 'np.inexact' or 'np.floating' to a dtype is deprecated. The current result is 'float64' which is not strictly correct.`

Comment: However using `c.dtype == np.double` did work for me. More information on numpy type names here: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.types.html

Comment: For me the warning @CraigReynolds describes disappears when I test for `c.dtype == float` instead of `c.dtype == np.floating` I'm not quite sure how equivalent those tests are, but in my case I get the expected results.

Comment: Thanks @Malo Pocheau. I was so young and naive way back then, ~4 month ago, being new to Python, numpy, deep learning...

Answer (score 1):

All entries in a numpy array are of the same type. The numpy type and the Python type are not the same thing. This can be a bit confusing, but the type numpy refers to is more like the types used by languages like C - you might say more low level closer the the machine.

You can not say which type is better, because it would be like comparing apple and oranges.

Comment: You should say `all entries ... are of the same dtype`, and `numpy dtype`.  The type of an array is `ndarray`, regardless of its `dtype`.

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a small wrapper which works basically like `isinstance` and accepts an object `o` and a class (or tuple of classes) `c`.
The only difference is if `isinstance(o, np.ndarray)` is `True`, `o.flat[0]` is checked against a mapped numpy data type (see the dict `c2np`)
I mostly work with `bool`, `int`, `float`, `str` but this list can be changed / extended.
Note that `np.integer` and `np.floating` are collections of most / all? available numpy subtypes as np.int8, np.unit16, ...

```py
def np_isinstance(o, c):
    c2np = {bool: np.bool, int: np.integer, float: np.floating, str: np.str}

    if isinstance(o, np.ndarray):
        c = (c2np[cc] for cc in c) if isinstance(c, tuple) else c2np[c]
        return isinstance(o.flat[0], c)

    else:
        return isinstance(o, c)
```

Some examples:

```py
# Like isinstance if o is not np.ndarray
np_isinstance(('this', 'that'), tuple)  # True
np_isinstance(4.4, int)                 # False
np_isinstance(4.4, float)               # True

#
np_isinstance(np.ones(4, dtype=int), int)    # True
np_isinstance(np.ones(4, dtype=int), float)  # False
np_isinstance(np.full((4, 4), 'bert'), str)  # True
```

Comment: This fails for bool, and is strictly inferior to a dtype check.