# In Python, how would you check if a number is one of the integer types?

Tags: python, numpy, types, int

In Python, how could you check if the type of a number is an integer without checking each integer type, i.e., `'int'`, `'numpy.int32'`, or `'numpy.int64'`?

I thought to try `if int(val) == val` but this does not work when a float is set to an integer value (not type).

```
In [1]: vals = [3, np.ones(1, dtype=np.int32)[0], np.zeros(1, dtype=np.int64)[0], np.ones(1)[0]]
In [2]: for val in vals:
   ...:     print(type(val))
   ...:     if int(val) == val: 
   ...:         print('{} is an int'.format(val))
<class 'int'>
3 is an int
<class 'numpy.int32'>
1 is an int
<class 'numpy.int64'>
0 is an int
<class 'numpy.float64'>
1.0 is an int
```

I want to filter out the last value, which is a `numpy.float64`.

Comment: If it is an array (or `np` datatype) you check the `dtype`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312013/check-type-within-numpy-array.  As note there, `arr[0].item()` will extract the item to a Python numeric type.

Comment: @hpaulj, I am considering only a single value, not an array.  I used a list to demonstrate in this example.

Comment: The single value still has `numpy` wrapper.  Use `item()` to remove that.

Comment: @hpaulj, `item()` work with numpy objects but crashes if the number is already a Python numeric type.  It could be used in a `try: except:` clause, but not a one line `if` statement.

Comment: Look at the `np.float64.__mro__` (and same for other `dtypes`).  Since `float` is in that list `isinstance(np.float64(2), float)` returns `True`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `isinstance` with a tuple argument containing the types of interest.

To capture all python and numpy integer types use:

```
isinstance(value, (int, np.integer))
```

Here is an example showing the results for several data types:

```
vals = [3, np.int32(2), np.int64(1), np.float64(0)]
[(e, type(e), isinstance(e, (int, np.integer))) for e in vals]
```

Result:

```
[(3, <type 'int'>, True), 
 (2, <type 'numpy.int32'>, True), 
 (1, <type 'numpy.int64'>, True), 
 (0.0, <type 'numpy.float64'>, False)]
```

A second example which is true only for int and int64:

```
[(e, type(e), isinstance(e, (int, np.int64))) for e in vals]
```

Result:

```
[(3, <type 'int'>, True), 
(1, <type 'numpy.int32'>, False), 
(0, <type 'numpy.int64'>, True), 
(0.0, <type 'numpy.float64'>, False)]
```

Comment: What version of numpy are you using? Because when I try that I get different results.

Comment: `np__version__` is 1.11.2

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo, I have the same as @dawg: `np.__version__` is `'1.11.2'`.

Comment: @StevenC.Howell Yeah it works now, it initially said `np.int` which gave a wrong answer.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the accepted answer, the standard library also provides the [`numbers`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/numbers.html) module, which defines abstract classes for numerical types that can be used with `isinstance`:

```
isinstance(value, numbers.Integral)
```

This can be used to recognize both Python's `int` as well as NumPy's `np.int64`.

Answer (score 4):

Use `np.issubdtype`:

```
for val in vals:
    if isinstance(val, int) or np.issubdtype(val, np.int):
        print('{} is an int'.format(val))
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution appears to be:

```
isinstance(value, (int, np.integer))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use duck typing:

```
hasattr(val, "denominator") and val.denominator == 1
```