# How to check the type of the values within a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

I have a bunch of numpy arrays, and i'm trying to check the type of the values within each array as some of them contain stars which cause the entire array to become of type string and others are floats. I want to be able to check an array and see if it contains floats or strings. Code below:

```
nums = np.array([123, 54, 645, 89, 465, 98])
nums2 = np.array(['4', '987', '*65*', '89'])
```

Is there a way to write some kind of loop to check this? My ideal output would be along the lines of:

```
nums = float
nums2 = string
```

Comment: In your example `nums` and `nums2` aren't numpy arrays but  plain python lists. Did you mean `nums = np.array([123, 54, 645, 89, 465, 98])`?

Comment: I do sorry let me edit that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check type within numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40312013/check-type-within-numpy-array)

Comment: `nums2` isn't valid python. Are you missing some quotes?

Comment: Does the source list contain numbers or strings?  The starred element has to be a string, but what of the others?  What's the dtype of the arrays?

Answer (score 2):

What you have there are lists. To make a NumPy array, you need to use its constructor as:

```
import numpy as np
nums = np.array([123, 54, 645, 89, 465, 98])
nums2 = np.array(['45', '987', '65', '89'])
```

NumPy arrays have an attribute called dtype. You can use that to see what type of data you have in your arrays.

```
>>> nums.dtype
dtype('int64')
>>> nums2.dtype
dtype('<U3')
```

For more info on NumPy data types: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html